# Independence of random vectors - proof

Tags: probability, random-variables, independence

I have a problem to solve but my intuitive solution seems far too easy

> Given three random Vectors X, Y, Z.
>
> If we know that X, Y are independent, and Z and (X´, Y´)´ are independent, I have to show that  X, Y, and Z are independent.

My idea:

$$P(X<x, Y<y, Z<z)=P(X<x)*P(Y<y,Z<z)=P(X<x)*P(Y<y)*P(Z<z)$$

which would show independence. But I am not sure if this would prove it. It feels like I am missing a point here.

Answer (score 1):

You have considered random variables, not random vectors. Your first step is not correct. The correct argument (in the case of random variables) is $$P(X<x,Y<y,Z<z)=P(X<x,Y<y)P(Z<z)$$ $$=P(X<x)P(Y<y)P(Z<z)$$ where the first equality holds because $Z$ is in dependent of $(X,Y)$ and the second equality is because $X$ and $Y$ are independent.

Comment: Many thanks to your answer! why the greater sign in P(X<x, Y<y, Z>z) ? and what would change if I consider random vectors?

Comment: $Z>z$ was a typo. A similar argument can b e given for random vectors. You have to replace $X<x$ by $X_1<x_1,X_2<x_2,..,X_n<x_n$ where $X=(X_1,X_2,..,X_n)$.  @Lillys